# mysql_real_escape_string() but allow names with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a common thing but I have a question. Allow apostrophes while still maintaining the `mysql_real_escape_string()` tag.

I have this: `$name = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stadium_name']));`

and I test it on this:

```
$getInfoX = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stadiums` WHERE `stadium_name` = '$stadium_name'")) or die(mysql_error());
```

I could do an example inject like `x'; DROP TABLE members; --` or a name with apostrophes like `Stade de l'Aube`... but the name with apostrophes get me an error like:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Aube'' at line 1`

What do I do?

Comment: use PDO or MySQLI, [read article for more info: Best way to prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string will deal with this for you. The error youre getting is from a mysql and not php yes?

Comment: Why are you still stripping slashes after `mysql_real_escape_string` has escaped it for you?

Comment: Your problem is the `stripslashes()`. Remove that. (Dates back to magic_quotes workarounds. But here it's applied in the wrong order even.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chain the result of `mysql_real_escape_string` through `stripslashes` which basically removes everything `mysql_real_escape_string` added for safety reasons.

So if you have `$stadium_name= "Fred's Stadium";` as input `mysql_real_escape_string($stadium_name)` returns `"Fred\'s Stadium"` which can be included into you query safely generating

```
"SELECT * FROM `stadiums` WHERE `stadium_name` = 'Fred\'s Stadium'"
```

as MySQL-query. Calling `stripslashes` on the `mysql_real_escape_string`output removes the \ in front of the ' so you send the query

```
"SELECT * FROM `stadiums` WHERE `stadium_name` = 'Fred's Stadium'"
```

to MySQL thinks your string is 'Fred' followed by some garbage (which can turn out to be dangerous).

Solution is to use a separate variable to store the result of mysql_real_escape_string, as it is correct for usage in database queries but unsuitable to be displayed back to the user.

I hope this helps.

Regards

TC

Comment: So, store it using mysql_real_escape_string but when displayed ... use  strip_slashes?

Comment: Yep and use php.net/htmlentities before echoing it so you don't get HTML injected into you pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
$name = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stadium_name']));
```

[`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) undoes the escaping.

You've probably seen that function used as workaround for [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes). If you were to apply it, then do so **before** the database escaping function.